# Matplotlib plot label truncates

Tags: matplotlib

I'm working on a Horizontal Bar and added bar label. The first bar's label should show 1,857,045 which is 7 digits but as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F02gR.png) it weirdly truncates and displays 1,85704e+06. I want the label to display the whole number but couldn't find which parameters of bar_label I should change.

Below is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.title(f"Refugees Fleeing Ukraine by Country as of {last_date}", fontsize=20)

ax.bar_label(container=ax.barh(list(countries_refugees.keys()), list(countries_refugees.values())), label_type="edge", padding=2, fontsize=15)

ax.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=20)
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)


plt.xlim([0, 2100000])
plt.xlabel("Number of Refugees", fontsize=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Question is how can I make the actual number to be displayed as the bar's label rather than this weird truncation?

Comment: Thank you for adding some test code.  However, some simple test data seem to still be missing.  Did you experiment with the `fmt=` parameter?  `ax.bar_label(..., fmt='%.0f')` seems to be a valid approach.  You might add `ax.margins(x=0.2)` to make more space for the labels. (Note that nesting `ax.barh(...)` inside `ax.bar_label(...)` isn't recommended, as it leads to difficult to read and difficult to maintain code.)

Comment: ax.bar_label(..., fmt='%.0f') this worked perfectly, thank you very much! I didn't start by nesting the ax.barh(..) but couldn't add the data labels otherwise.